# Javascript if statement ignored

Tags: jquery, asp.net, if-statement, code-behind, keyup

i'm new to asp.net and busy with a tutorial website.

I'm trying to call a server side function using an if statement, the problem is that the if statement is completely ignored i.e the function is called regardless.

This works when using a normal js alert

code below:

```
$(function () {
    $("#idnum").keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.length == 13) { 
            <%= TextBox1_TextChanged(this, idnum.Text) %> ; 
            //call code behind function to get contact info with ID
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't call server methods like that. Your method is called when the page is generated not by the JavaScript code.

Comment: You just can't do this. The fact it works with an alert is because you're rendering text from server, then executiong client code (javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke server side methods on client with your code. Try to use [PageMethods](http://www.techillumination.in/2013/07/an-aspnet-way-to-call-server-side.html) in order to call server side method from client.

Comment: i have used the PageMethods as below but this is not calling the function

Comment: $(function () {
            $("#idnum").keyup(function () {
                if (this.value.length == 13) {
                    PageMethods.getID(this.value);  //call code behind function to get contact info with ID
                }        
        });
        });

Comment: Before running the code don't forget to include the Script Manager in your aspx page and also enable the page methods.

Comment: i have also tried to use scriptmethod as suggested here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658061/calling-asp-net-page-method-from-javascript-not-working)