# ASP.NET PageMethod onSuccess function returns a HTML String

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

This is weird. My onSuccess() function in the javascript file returns a massive **HTML Code of my entire web page** instead of the value I actually return from my C# WebMethod

> 1) I am running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10
>
> 2) When debugged, I kept a breakpoint at the SignupAccount C# method. The breakpoint was not hit. It didn't get to that point. BUT the onSuccess function was called

Here's an explanation:

**ASP.NET Web Form's HTML:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
   <!--Code-->
 </head>
 <body class="account2 signup" data-page="signup">
   <!--Code-->
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>

    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required autofocus>

    <button type="submit" onclick="signup()" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-rounded" data-style="expand-left">Sign In</button>

    <script src="JS/Account.js"></script>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**WebMethod in C# Code Behind:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SignupAccount(string fname, string lname)
{
    return "OK";
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function signup() {
    var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;

    PageMethods.SignupAccount(fname, lname, onSuccess, onFailure);

    function onSuccess(val) {
       alert(val);
       //Technically, this should display "OK". But instead it displays a HTML String 
       //of my entire Web Page starting from the <html> tag to the end
    }

    function onFailure() {}
}
```

Why is it happening? I believe the procedure and the code is correct. Is this something to do with Visual Studio?

**EDIT**

This is the response I get from the onSuccess function

http://pastebin.com/6MjAFPY9

Comment: Are you seeing any XHR entry to SignupAccount in browser Developer Tools -> Network Tab ?

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu No I dont see any entry there. I tried creating a new web form with only a button and a web method and I still get this massive html string as the onSuccess return value. I think there's an issue with the config

Comment: it could be duplicate to : [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658061/calling-asp-net-page-method-from-javascript-not-working)

Comment: Perhaps the user isn't logged in, and they're being redirected to the login page..? Do you need to mark your `SignupAccount` as allowing anonymous users?

Comment: @Rob Keeping the Signup example aside, I created a brand new web form with just a button and a WebMethod that returns "OK". I Still get this massive HTML String. I will edit the return value to the question now

Comment: As mentioned in [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658061/calling-asp-net-page-method-from-javascript-not-working) add [ScriptMethod] in addition to [WebMethod]

Comment: @Rob This is what I get http://pastebin.com/6MjAFPY9

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu I will try that now

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu Nope no luck mate

Comment: you need to return false while calling the java script function to stop page submit. Like this onclick="signup(); return false;"

Comment: try [WebMethod(true)]  good luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, the problem was in my `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`.

1. **Remove**

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

2. If `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);` is in there too, add `PageMethods.set_path` to the **JavaScript file**, before your WebMethod call:

```
...

PageMethods.set_path("YourPage.aspx");
PageMethods.SignupAccount(fname, lname, onSuccess, onFailure);

...
```

The answer is puzzled together from:

- [PageMethod and URl Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321240/pagemethod-and-url-rewrite)
- [ASP.NET Calling WebMethod with jQuery AJAX "401 (Unauthorized)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033614/asp-net-calling-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax-401-unauthorized)

Comment: This solution works equally well with the asp.net OnClientClick="blahblah(); return false;" OR using a javascript event handler. Recommend Mark as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created project on machine, working code is below:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:TextBox ID="firstname" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="lastname" runat="server" />

    <asp:Button ID="btn" OnClientClick ="signup();return false;" runat="server" text="Call PageMethod" />

</form>

<script>
    function signup() {
        var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;

        PageMethods.SignupAccount(fname, lname, onSuccess, onFailure);

        function onSuccess(val) {
            alert(val);
            //Technically, this should display "OK". But instead it displays a HTML String 
            //of my entire Web Page starting from the <html> tag to the end
        }

        function onFailure() { }
    }
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string SignupAccount(string fname, string lname)
    {
        return "OK";
    }
```

PS: Ensure you don't have any JavaScript errors on the page. Hope this helps!

Comment: I copied the exact same code and I still got the same response: http://pastebin.com/6MjAFPY9

Comment: Any javascript error ? Use Developer Tools in browser.

Comment: This is very weird. No errors either! The breakpoints don't get fired either. Simply goes to the onSuccess and returns that massive html code

Comment: did you ever found a solution to your issue? I have been struggling with the exact same issue for a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it. First, remove the `onclick` attribute from the `button` tag:

```
<!-- before -->
<button type="submit" id="submit-form" onclick="signup()">Sign In</button>

<!-- after -->
<button type="submit" id="submit-form">Sign In</button>
```

Then replace it with this line of Javascript:

```
$get('submit-form').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    signup();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The default event handler for the button's click event will cause the page to be submitted, so we need to call `preventDefault` [[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) [[2]](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) to inhibit this.